# unknown sequences of rational numbers with sum of a transcendental number

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, transcendental-number-theory

Starting with a transcendental number like $e$, it is known that we can write it as a sum of infinitely many rational numbers of the form :

$e= \sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty }{\dfrac {1}{n!}}={\frac {1}{1}}+{\frac {1}{1}}+{\frac {1}{1\cdot 2}}+{\frac {1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}}+\cdots $

we can see in this form each element here is defined and is related to other elements by a known order.

a question comes to mind here about existance of a sequence of positive rational numbers $\{\omega _n\}\subset\mathbb{Q}^+$ satisfying conditions below:

1. $ e= \sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty }\omega_n$
2. each element $\omega_i$ is not predefined (means it is unknown to us, we just know it is positive rational number).
3. there be no known order or trend (except the well ordering assortment) between elements of the sequence  $\{\omega _n\}$ (means there is no defined relation for example like $\sim$ between elements of any subset of $\{\omega _n\}$).
4. there be no defined algorithm by which $\{\omega _n\}$ be constructed from $\{\dfrac {1}{n!}\}$ or any other known sequence with sum of $e$.

   note: here conditions 3 and 4 may correlate eachother but I mentioned both for more accurate explanation.

It seems here there are some feelings of ambiguity around how this question is phrased as it was put on hold in mathexchange but also may seems some fundamental issues with it, because of this I think
we should first investigate whether this question is undecidable or not under the ZFC axiomatic system but I don't know how?

As two answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002328/unknown-sequences-with-sum-of-e/3002376?noredirect=1#comment6193896_3002376) in mathexchange was in a way that represents a few knowledge of their authors about such these kind of problems ,I've decided to also present it in research level community in order to find some knowledge or at least some source related to the topic,thanks.

Comment: You can choose $\omega_1,\omega_3,\omega_5,\dots$ arbitrarily, so long as they approach zero, so there's an uncountable infinity of sequences satisfying all your constraints.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry sir, I didn't get your point ,would you please explain it more?

Comment: No. The question doesn't belong here, so I have said all I'm going to say about it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson at least would you please say where should I ask my question sir?

Comment: @MasM , Mathstackexhange would be more appropriate.

Comment: @JoshuaZ I asked there as I mentioned but they had put on hold without any appropriate answer or any obvious reason like here .I don't know what is the problem with my question, nobody even say anything about it or edit it!

Comment: "they had put on hold without ... any obvious reason" There certainly was a reason given at m.se: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question." So, the ball is in your court, MasM.

Comment: @GerryMyerson personally I don't know what's wrong with the question ,I wish there be someone suggesting an edit in order to make the question in-topic.

Comment: What's wrong with the question is that no one, perhaps including yourself, has any idea what you are talking about. It might help if you forgot about $e$ and just gave an example of a sequence of positive rationals satisfying conditions 2 and 3 (or 2, 3, and 4).